# Adding buttons to my vertical slide menu CS3

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a menu that slides out from the left, much like you'd see on a phone app or site. I have very little knowledge of the codes used in CS3, but I have found a code that creates the animation. However, what I don't know how to do is to add buttons to the animation. How would I make clickable buttons on that disappear when the menu retracts?

Here is the link to my (stolen) code http://jsfiddle.net/2vLjU/8864/

and the code here for the lazy: 
CSS:

```
.wrapper {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
width: 300px;
height: 1000px; 
border: 0px solid black;}

#slide {
position: absolute;
left: -230px;
width: 300px;
height: 925px;
transition: 1s;}


.wrapper:hover #slide {
transition: 1s;
left: 0;}
```

Comment: CS3 is Creative Suite 3 by Adobe?

Comment: @connexo Sorry about that, I meant Adobe Dreamweaver CS3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now that code is only animating the image.

I would create a div with the id `slide` instead. Then put whatever link you want for your navigation in that div so they move with the animation.

If you want that image to move with it as well you can set it as the `background-image` instead of using the `<img>` tag.

Hope that helps.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="slide">
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```